# Selenium can't connect to any driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the latest version of Selenium for python (Installed by doing `pip install selenium`, it installed version `2.53.6`) and am running OS X 10.11.5.

If I try to do `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` a message comes up `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: .... If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`.

I did `brew install chromedriver`. If I try to do `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` a message comes up `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver`.

I did `npm install -g phantomjs`. If I try to do `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()` a message comes up `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service phantomjs`.

I tried to Google and solve all these issues with these three drivers. Nothing seems to work. I am not sure if the port that selenium needs is being blocked or something, but I am out of ideas. It seems to be a fundamental problem with Selenium itself as all three drivers are failing. Anyone have a clue why?

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have installed? Have you tried upgrading `chromedriver` and `phantomjs`? Thanks.

Comment: I have the latest Firefox (47.0.1), but read somewhere that v47 and selenium don't get along so I tried to downgrade (v44) and that didn't work either. Maybe another version definitely works with selenium? And I have chromedriver `ChromeDriver 2.22.397929` and PhantomJS `2.1.1`

Comment: Thanks, please try firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: @alecxe with the latest version of selenium or a specific one?

Comment: Yeah, latest selenium and firefox 46.0.1. Tried locally, works for me..

Comment: Just tried, not working for me :/ Maybe the port is in use. Python for Selenium uses port `4444`?